# Sum numbers up to N-M in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

Hey I need to make a function countNM(N,M,S) that sums all the numbers up to N-M (and returns 0 if N is equal to or less than M). I have worked it out and what I have makes sense when I work through it in my head, but something is uninstantiated...

```
sumNM(0,0,0).
sumNM(N,M,S):-
    N=<M,
    S is 0.
sumNM(N,M,S):-
    N>M,
    A is N-M,
    B is S+A,
    C is M+1,
    sumNM(N,C,B).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the line

```
B is S+A,
```

At this point, `S` is not bound, causing the arithmetic expression to fail.

Other than that, the logic behind this expression is also wrong. What you're saying is that the sum of one fewer number (B) is equal to the total sum (S) plus the current number (A). This should be the other way around.

You can replace the last predicate with this code:

```
sumNM(N,M,S):-
    N>M,
    A is N-M,
    C is M+1,
    sumNM(N,C,B),
    S is B+A.
```

Here we first calculate the sum B, after which we add A to it, resulting in the total sum S.

Comment: That works, thank you. I guess it's just hard for me to wrap my head around prolog logic here. It seems counterintuitive to run the recursive function first incrementing M up and then adding the two previous functions together... Before I was thinking you take the sum so far and add the current number.

Comment: That's also a possible approach, but it requires another parameter (called an accumulator). You may want to try it out as an exercise, but there is definitely nothing wrong with the current approach.

Comment: You're a wizard, Steven. I'm just wondering how B is instantiated here. It seems to me, for example if you input sumNM(5,1,S), it would run sumNM(5,2,B) and B is still blank. Why does this work?

Comment: Before calling sumNM(5,2,B), B is indeed still blank, but it will have a value after the call is complete. sumNM(5,2,B) will in turn call sumNM(5,3,B), which will call sumNM(5,4,B), which will call sumNM(5,5,B), which unifies S (at that point) with 0. After that, each level of recursion will add their current value to this sum B, which is their own sum S.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual problem.

While @Steven found the principal problem there are other issues. Namely, you have four clauses when two will do. (**Edit**: I misread the question due to improper indentation, as mentioned by @Steven below. The "fourth clause" does not exist.) You can delete the first and fourth: `sumNM(0,0,0)` actually matches two of the other clauses (0 =< 0 after all) and the fourth clause is an "anything goes" clause that probably shouldn't be there at all. For instance, `sumNM(50,45,N)` yields `N = 15` and `sumNM(50,45,15)` unifies once and then winds up creating an exception because N is unbound. Why? Because the last clause basically passes anything. `sumNM(50,45,10000000)` also unifies and that seems obviously untrue. But `sumNM(_,_,_)` means "any three things are related by `sumNM/3`." And there's no difference between `sumNM(N,C,B)` and `sumNM(_,_,_)`: that's why you're getting the singleton variable warning. If you find this surprising, it points to a misunderstanding about the nature of variables somewhere.

In cases like this where you really have an exclusion it's probably simplest (and leads to fewer spurious choice points/solutions) to use an if/else construct. I would therefore recommend the following implementation:

```
sumNM(N,M,S):-
    (
        N =< M
    ->
        S is 0
    ;
        A is N-M,
        C is M+1,
        sumNM(N,C,B),
        S is B+A
    ).
```

Note that this implementation is still only partially correct! This now works (and notice we do not get prompted for additional solutions, without having to employ the cut):

```
?- sumNM(50,45,15).
true.
?- sumNM(50,45,20000000).
false.
```

But this still doesn't:

```
?- sumNM(50,X,Y).
ERROR: =</2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

The situation could probably be corrected by use of [clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) but I won't be able to help you get there.

Comment: You're right about the first clause, I didn't bother mentioning it. There is no fourth clause however. The last line is part of the third clause, it just looks like a fourth clause due to improper indentation. Other than that this is a completely valid answer though.